# Generating combinations of values from a list of lists python

Tags: python

I want to get the combinations of a list of list, for example

```
[['a0', 'a1'], ['b0', 'b1'], ['c0', 'c1', 'c2']]
```

I can use `list(itertools.product(*listOfTuples))` and get

```
[('a0', 'b0', 'c0'), ('a0', 'b0', 'c1'), ('a0', 'b0', 'c2')... ('a1', 'b1', 'c2')]
```

How would I get a list with the possible combinations of length 2? For example:

```
[('a0', 'b0'), ('a0', 'c0'), ('b0', 'c0')...
```

Comment: Should all the elements of the sublists be unique relative to the initial letters?

Comment: Is `('a0', 'a1')` a valid combination of length 2, i.e. 2 from the same original group?

Comment: This is straightforwardly a matter of getting each pair of lists that you want to feed to `itertools.product`, and then iteratively doing so. Those pairs are `itertools.combinations` of the list of lists. I have accordingly closed this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call `itertools.combinations()` with `r=2` to get all pairs of each triple and then flatten, e.g.:

```
In []:
import itertools as it
[t for x in it.product(*s) for t in it.combinations(x, r=2)]

Out[]:
[('a0', 'b0'), ('a0', 'c0'), ('b0', 'c0'), ('a0', 'b0'), ('a0', 'c1'), ('b0', 'c1'),
 ('a0', 'b0'), ('a0', 'c2'), ('b0', 'c2'), ('a0', 'b1'), ('a0', 'c0'), ('b1', 'c0'), 
 ('a0', 'b1'), ('a0', 'c1'), ('b1', 'c1'), ('a0', 'b1'), ('a0', 'c2'), ('b1', 'c2'), 
 ('a1', 'b0'), ('a1', 'c0'), ('b0', 'c0'), ('a1', 'b0'), ('a1', 'c1'), ('b0', 'c1'), 
 ('a1', 'b0'), ('a1', 'c2'), ('b0', 'c2'), ('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'c0'), ('b1', 'c0'), 
 ('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'c1'), ('b1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'c2'), ('b1', 'c2')]
```

However, this will have duplicates because of `('a0', 'b0', 'c0')`, `('a0', 'b0', 'c1')` and `('a0', 'b0', 'c2')` all generate `('a0', 'b0')`, so if you want to remove then you can just use a `set`, but you lose order:

```
In []:
{t for x in it.product(*s) for t in it.combinations(x, r=2)}

Out[]:
{('a1', 'c0'), ('b0', 'c1'), ('b0', 'c2'), ('a0', 'c1'), ('a0', 'c2'), ('b1', 'c1'), 
 ('b1', 'c2'), ('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'c2'), ('b0', 'c0'), ('a0', 'c0'), 
 ('a1', 'b0'), ('b1', 'c0'), ('a0', 'b1'), ('a0', 'b0')}
```

Sorting it does put it back in order:

```
In []:
sorted({t for x in it.product(*s) for t in it.combinations(x, r=2)})

Out[]:
[('a0', 'b0'), ('a0', 'b1'), ('a0', 'c0'), ('a0', 'c1'), ('a0', 'c2'), ('a1', 'b0'), 
 ('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'c0'), ('a1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'c2'), ('b0', 'c0'), ('b0', 'c1'), 
 ('b0', 'c2'), ('b1', 'c0'), ('b1', 'c1'), ('b1', 'c2')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten your list, and create a simple recursive function (for results without repetition in the sublists):

```
d = [['a0', 'a1'], ['b0', 'b1'], ['c0', 'c1', 'c2']]
def combinations(d, current = []):
  if len(current) == 2:
    yield current
  else:
    for i in d:
      if i not in current:
        yield from combinations(d, current+[i])

print(list(combinations([i for b in d for i in b]))
```

Output:

```
[['a0', 'a1'], ['a0', 'b0'], ['a0', 'b1'], ['a0', 'c0'], ['a0', 'c1'], ['a0', 'c2'], ['a1', 'a0'], ['a1', 'b0'], ['a1', 'b1'], ['a1', 'c0'], ['a1', 'c1'], ['a1', 'c2'], ['b0', 'a0'], ['b0', 'a1'], ['b0', 'b1'], ['b0', 'c0'], ['b0', 'c1'], ['b0', 'c2'], ['b1', 'a0'], ['b1', 'a1'], ['b1', 'b0'], ['b1', 'c0'], ['b1', 'c1'], ['b1', 'c2'], ['c0', 'a0'], ['c0', 'a1'], ['c0', 'b0'], ['c0', 'b1'], ['c0', 'c1'], ['c0', 'c2'], ['c1', 'a0'], ['c1', 'a1'], ['c1', 'b0'], ['c1', 'b1'], ['c1', 'c0'], ['c1', 'c2'], ['c2', 'a0'], ['c2', 'a1'], ['c2', 'b0'], ['c2', 'b1'], ['c2', 'c0'], ['c2', 'c1']]
```